# CMake target_sources with different targets

Tags: c++, cmake

With cmake we can split a project in multiple subfolders.
From the top CMakeLists.txt we then call the sub CMakeLists.txt With

```
add_subdirectory(moduleb)
```

And each sub CMakeLists.txt will have an

```
target_sources(target SOURCES)
```

But what if I want to use the sub CMakeLists in multiple different top level projects?
The limited understanding of CMakeLists I have seems to sugests I have to go on each sub folders and edit the CMakeList changing the target name.
There must be an smarter way of dealing with this, isn't?

Comment: Yes each target needs a different name, if you give your targets meaningful names it shouldn't be too much of a problem?

Comment: Why no static libraries? (Or is it necessary to compile the sources with different options? An interface lib with interface sources would be another approach. If everything else fails you could still set a variable containing the name of the target. In general I'd refrain from creating `CMakeLists.txt` files containing no target btw.

Comment: So if you just split the source files in multiple folders without planning to make libraries on that folders, 
your suggestion is to have a single top level CMakeLists.txt?